# 'y is undefined' Javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

sorry i'm very new to JS, i'm trying to write some code to dynamically count the words on a page, this code is within a 'whenkeydown' function:

```
var text = $(this).val();

var word=text.split(" ")

    //word counter
function countWords(word, text) {
    var y = word.value; 
    var words = 0;
    a = y.replace(/\s/g, ' ');
    a = a.split(' ');
    for ( z = 0; z < a.length; z++) {
        if (a[z].length > 0)
            words++;
    }
    wordCount = words;
}
```

But i get an error message saying "TypeError: y is undefined" in the debugger? 
Thanks

Comment: How and where are you calling `countWords`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `whenkeydown` function ... or did you create one?

Comment: Please include the code where you actually call the `countWords` function.  It’s impossible to see what the problem is if you don’t include that.

Comment: You initialize `words` with 0, but then you increase `r`, in the end you pass 0 to `wordCount` because you never changed `words`

Comment: @ECH : you have defined var y inside the function , are you using it outside the function ?????

Comment: text.split(" ") will return array

Comment: @Murali It will, but that's irrelevant. `word` outside of the `countWords` function and `word` inside the `countWords` function don't have any relation to each other in the context of the code provided.

Comment: @Anthony Grist, Yes i agree.  sorry for misunderstood

Comment: CyberDude word value is what i thought was needed so we can distinguish words - i based the code on this - http://javascript.about.com/library/blcount.htm

@Cerbrus i'm displaying countWords under a text box - using:
       $("#noOfWords").html("").html(countWords).css("color", "#000000");
devnull69 sorry i included the original code, i edited 'r' out now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`word` is an array, it does not have attribute `value`. Moreover your functions seems to accept the whole string as a parameter, not an array of words. Here is a clearer version:

```
function countWords(text) {
    var words = text.replace(/\s/g, ' ').split(' ');
    var wordCount = 0;
    for (var z = 0; z < words.length; z++) {
        if (words[z].length > 0)
            wordCount++;
    }

    return wordCount;
}

var text = $(this).val();
var wordCount = countWords(text);
```

Comment: `word` is an array **outside** of the `countWords` function, inside that function it could be absolutely anything - including a reference to an `<input>` which *would* have a `value` property.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, true enough. However I assumed that `word` originates from the line in the beginning of the question, and was just used improperly inside the function.

Comment: Best solution here so far, [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMRjm/1/) with a live test case.

Comment: @Andrei thankyou, it was simply my carelessness in replicating the approach i originally saw, this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
function countWords(wordsArray) {
  var words = 0;
  try{ 
    for(k in wordsArray){
      var sa = (wordsArray[k]  ? word.value.replace(/\s/g, ' ') : '').split(' ');
      for (i in sa) if(sa[i].trim()) words++;
    }
  catch(ex){}
  return words;
}
```

OR:

```
$(this).val().match(/\S+/g).length;
```